# Error build APK QT Creator - building the android package failed

Tags: android, qt, ant, build, qt-creator

On my Mac I've installed QT Creator.
Deploy on iOS works, but on Android Device don't work.

This is the error:

> Build failed
>   Building the android package failed!
>     -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.
>   12:52:13: The process "/Users/myuser/Qt/5.8/android_armv7/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with code 14.
>   Error while building/deploying project test (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.8.0))
>   When executing step "Build Android APK"

In the options every settings are set.

SDK are set, NDK are set, JDK are set. Apache ANT are set.

I don't understand because don't work.
I use qt creator 5.8 on Mac OS Sierra.
Any solution ?

Comment: Have you actually run the suggested command with the --verbose option?

Comment: how set verbose on debug mode in QT ?

Comment: try to recreate manifests from project tab

Answer (score 1):

You have to download tools folder from that link https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.2.5-macosx.zip
When the download is finished, you have to replace the tools folder of your android folder, in my case, that folder is in /home/agustin/Android/Sdk/tools because im using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved with this guide, deploy section.

https://v-play.net/doc/vplay-deployment/#android-deployment

In short words:
Download SDK and NDK from google site and not from sdk manager of Android Studio. 
Set in QT creator and Deploy it.